# how to store the print in the variable while keep printing on the screen?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command that keeps printing on the screen. I have to collect its print to do something, while, I have to supervise the print.

How could I do that in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
VAR=$(my_cmd --args ... | tee /dev/stderr)
```

`tee` outputs to the screen and a file at the same time. But, here we specify `stderr`, which is another stream that goes to the screen. The variable captures `stdout`, and `tee` puts a copy of that output on `stderr` which goes to your screen.

Comment: Then you can collect the output in your variable as `VAR=$(cat logfile.txt)` afterwards.

Comment: no smarter way? the command gets called frequently, i will spread files everywhere.

Comment: There, you can use `/dev/stderr` to avoid the temp file. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate your stdout:

```
exec 9>&1
variable=$(date |tee >(cat - >&9))
echo "Variable contains: $variable"
```

prints:

```
Thu Oct  2 21:21:52 CEST 2014   #normal output from the date
Variable contains: Thu Oct  2 21:21:52 CEST 2014     #the echo...
```

Comment: awesome. yours is clean and neat.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by up-voting helpful answers...